# upgrading powershell breaks it

Tags: powershell

I recently upgraded powershell using choco.

It looked like everything went fine, but now, I can't even open it anymore.
Whenever I try to run it, it just starts tons of powershell.exe processes that I can see in the task manager, and takes all memory.

I can't try to install another version of powershell, because [I need a working version of powershell to do so](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.1/install-configure#install-wmf-51-for-windows-server-2008-r2-and-windows-7), and I do not have one.

EDIT:
As suggested in comments, I could start powershell from the cmd.exe using -noProfile option. But now it says powershell is already up to date. Does it means I will have to get back to an old powershell version?

What can I do?
[image]

Comment: Try to use `-NoProfile` switch for PowerShell.

Comment: If with `-NoProfile` PowerShell work fine, than you should investigate what is in your profile and remove what should not be here.